# Import files in Cake Php 3.8

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.8

I am just trying to include a file in CakePhp but nothing helps me. I have placed that file inside the vendor folder.

Here's the path of that file:

> vendor/paytm/PaytmChecksum.php

**I tried to import it in my controller like below:**

```
require_once(ROOT  . DS .  'vendor'  . DS .  'paytm'  . DS .  'PaytmChecksum.php');
```

**But it didn't work. So, I tried another method by including below two lines at top of the controller.**

```
 use Cake\Filesystem\File;

 use Cake\Filesystem\Folder;
```

Then did this in the controller action:

```
$dir = new Folder(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'paytm' . DS . 'PaytmChecksum.php');
```

But nothing is working for me. I tried to place the folder in my current directory and then tried by including the file with `require_once` but that also not worked.

Can anyone please help with the same?

Comment: What does "But it didn't work" mean? Did you get errors? What are the details of those? Does the file in question have a namespace, or does it just put things in the global namespace?

Comment: I gave that lib file namespace "PaytmChecksum" and included "use  "paytm/PaytmCheckSum" and then created a new Object using "new PaytmChecksum()".

Comment: And it failed when you did `new PaytmChecksum()`?

Comment: If the namespace is just `PaytmChecksum`, then you should `use PaytmChecksum`, not `use paytm\PaytmChecksum`. But you can also simplify things for yourself if you set up a `composer.json` in the `paytm` folder with autoload information, then `composer dumpautoload`. Then you won't need the `require_once` at all, PHP will just know how to find that namespace.

Comment: Sir, Actually my files are hosted on cpanel. And I don't think I can run composer commands on cpanel.

Comment: If your files are *only* on cPanel, how did you ever install Cake and other dependencies? If your files are also on a dev system that you upload to cPanel from, why can you not do these steps on that dev system and upload it all?

Comment: Great idea. I will do the same and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I also Faced a problem in paytm checksum.
So i had created a files in Component.
`......\src\Controller\Component\PaytmChecksumComponent.php`

And the code is.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;

define('PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT', 'TEST'); // PROD
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY', '*********************'); //Change this constant's value with Merchant key received from Paytm.
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID', '*************'); //Change this constant's value with MID (Merchant ID) received from Paytm.
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE', 'WEBSTAGING'); //Change this constant's value with Website name received from Paytm.
define('PAYTM_REFUND_URL', '');

class PaytmChecksumComponent extends Component
{

    public $PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_NEW_URL = 'https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/merchant-status/getTxnStatus';
    public $PAYTM_TXN_URL = 'https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/processTransaction';
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        if (PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT == 'PROD') {
            $this->PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_NEW_URL = 'https://securegw.paytm.in/merchant-status/getTxnStatus';
            $this->PAYTM_TXN_URL = 'https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/processTransaction';
        }
        define('PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_URL', $this->PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_NEW_URL);
        define('PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_NEW_URL', $this->PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_NEW_URL);
        define('PAYTM_TXN_URL', $this->PAYTM_TXN_URL);
    }
    function encrypt_e($input, $ky)
    {
        $key   = html_entity_decode($ky);
        $iv = "@@@@&&&&####$$$$";
        $data = openssl_encrypt($input, "AES-128-CBC", $key, 0, $iv);
        return $data;
    }

    function decrypt_e($crypt, $ky)
    {
        $key   = html_entity_decode($ky);
        $iv = "@@@@&&&&####$$$$";
        $data = openssl_decrypt($crypt, "AES-128-CBC", $key, 0, $iv);
        return $data;
    }

    function generateSalt_e($length)
    {
        $random = "";
        srand((float) microtime() * 1000000);

        $data = "AbcDE123IJKLMN67QRSTUVWXYZ";
        $data .= "aBCdefghijklmn123opq45rs67tuv89wxyz";
        $data .= "0FGH45OP89";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $random .= substr($data, (rand() % (strlen($data))), 1);
        }

        return $random;
    }

    function checkString_e($value)
    {
        if ($value == 'null')
            $value = '';
        return $value;
    }

    function getChecksumFromArray($arrayList, $key, $sort = 1)
    {
        if ($sort != 0) {
            ksort($arrayList);
        }
        $str = $this->getArray2Str($arrayList);
        $salt = $this->generateSalt_e(4);
        $finalString = $str . "|" . $salt;
        $hash = hash("sha256", $finalString);
        $hashString = $hash . $salt;
        $checksum = $this->encrypt_e($hashString, $key);
        return $checksum;
    }
    function getChecksumFromString($str, $key)
    {

        $salt = $this->generateSalt_e(4);
        $finalString = $str . "|" . $salt;
        $hash = hash("sha256", $finalString);
        $hashString = $hash . $salt;
        $checksum = $this->encrypt_e($hashString, $key);
        return $checksum;
    }

    function verifychecksum_e($arrayList, $key, $checksumvalue)
    {
        $arrayList = $this->removeCheckSumParam($arrayList);
        ksort($arrayList);
        $str = $this->getArray2StrForVerify($arrayList);
        $paytm_hash = $this->decrypt_e($checksumvalue, $key);
        $salt = substr($paytm_hash, -4);

        $finalString = $str . "|" . $salt;

        $website_hash = hash("sha256", $finalString);
        $website_hash .= $salt;

        $validFlag = "FALSE";
        if ($website_hash == $paytm_hash) {
            $validFlag = "TRUE";
        } else {
            $validFlag = "FALSE";
        }
        return $validFlag;
    }

    function verifychecksum_eFromStr($str, $key, $checksumvalue)
    {
        $paytm_hash = $this->decrypt_e($checksumvalue, $key);
        $salt = substr($paytm_hash, -4);

        $finalString = $str . "|" . $salt;

        $website_hash = hash("sha256", $finalString);
        $website_hash .= $salt;

        $validFlag = "FALSE";
        if ($website_hash == $paytm_hash) {
            $validFlag = "TRUE";
        } else {
            $validFlag = "FALSE";
        }
        return $validFlag;
    }

    function getArray2Str($arrayList)
    {
        $findme   = 'REFUND';
        $findmepipe = '|';
        $paramStr = "";
        $flag = 1;
        foreach ($arrayList as $key => $value) {
            $pos = strpos($value, $findme);
            $pospipe = strpos($value, $findmepipe);
            if ($pos !== false || $pospipe !== false) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($flag) {
                $paramStr .= $this->checkString_e($value);
                $flag = 0;
            } else {
                $paramStr .= "|" . $this->checkString_e($value);
            }
        }
        return $paramStr;
    }

    function getArray2StrForVerify($arrayList)
    {
        $paramStr = "";
        $flag = 1;
        foreach ($arrayList as $key => $value) {
            if ($flag) {
                $paramStr .= $this->checkString_e($value);
                $flag = 0;
            } else {
                $paramStr .= "|" . $this->checkString_e($value);
            }
        }
        return $paramStr;
    }

    function redirect2PG($paramList, $key)
    {
        $hashString = $this->getchecksumFromArray($paramList, $key);
        $checksum = $this->encrypt_e($hashString, $key);
    }

    function removeCheckSumParam($arrayList)
    {
        if (isset($arrayList["CHECKSUMHASH"])) {
            unset($arrayList["CHECKSUMHASH"]);
        }
        return $arrayList;
    }

    function getTxnStatus($requestParamList)
    {
        return $this->callAPI(PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_URL, $requestParamList);
    }

    function getTxnStatusNew($requestParamList)
    {
        return $this->callNewAPI(PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_NEW_URL, $requestParamList);
    }

    function initiateTxnRefund($requestParamList)
    {
        $CHECKSUM = $this->getRefundChecksumFromArray($requestParamList, PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY, 0);
        $requestParamList["CHECKSUM"] = $CHECKSUM;
        return $this->callAPI(PAYTM_REFUND_URL, $requestParamList);
    }

    function callAPI($apiURL, $requestParamList)
    {
        $jsonResponse = "";
        $responseParamList = array();
        $JsonData = json_encode($requestParamList);
        $postData = 'JsonData=' . urlencode($JsonData);
        $ch = curl_init($apiURL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postData)
        ));
        $jsonResponse = curl_exec($ch);
        $responseParamList = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
        return $responseParamList;
    }

    function callNewAPI($apiURL, $requestParamList)
    {
        $jsonResponse = "";
        $responseParamList = array();
        $JsonData = json_encode($requestParamList);
        $postData = 'JsonData=' . urlencode($JsonData);
        $ch = curl_init($apiURL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postData)
        ));
        $jsonResponse = curl_exec($ch);
        $responseParamList = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
        return $responseParamList;
    }
    function getRefundChecksumFromArray($arrayList, $key, $sort = 1)
    {
        if ($sort != 0) {
            ksort($arrayList);
        }
        $str = $this->getRefundArray2Str($arrayList);
        $salt = $this->generateSalt_e(4);
        $finalString = $str . "|" . $salt;
        $hash = hash("sha256", $finalString);
        $hashString = $hash . $salt;
        $checksum = $this->encrypt_e($hashString, $key);
        return $checksum;
    }
    function getRefundArray2Str($arrayList)
    {
        $findmepipe = '|';
        $paramStr = "";
        $flag = 1;
        foreach ($arrayList as $key => $value) {
            $pospipe = strpos($value, $findmepipe);
            if ($pospipe !== false) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($flag) {
                $paramStr .= $this->checkString_e($value);
                $flag = 0;
            } else {
                $paramStr .= "|" . $this->checkString_e($value);
            }
        }
        return $paramStr;
    }
    function callRefundAPI($refundApiURL, $requestParamList)
    {
        $jsonResponse = "";
        $responseParamList = array();
        $JsonData = json_encode($requestParamList);
        $postData = 'JsonData=' . urlencode($JsonData);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $refundApiURL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $jsonResponse = curl_exec($ch);
        $responseParamList = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
        return $responseParamList;
    }
}
```

To load component in controller

```
public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();
        //....................................
        $this->loadComponent('PaytmChecksum');
        //........................
    }

    // .............
    function payment(){
    //...$paytmParams = array(
    "MID" => "*****",
    "WEBSITE" => "DEFAULT",
    "INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" => "1",
    "CHANNEL_ID" => "WEB",
    "ORDER_ID" => "*************",
    "CUST_ID" => "*****",
    "MOBILE_NO" => "*****",
    "EMAIL" => "*******",
    "TXN_AMOUNT" => (float)100,
    /* on completion of transaction, we will send you the response on this URL */
    "CALLBACK_URL" => "https://******",
    );
    $checksum = $this->PaytmChecksum->getChecksumFromArray($paytmParams, "_@C%&uL"); 
    pr($checksum);
    }
```

Comment: That's not a correct method. Anyways, I found the solution.